# Loading "Search Page" produces "404 Page Not Found" page when querying data

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a page ".com/listings" that loads well, but when I run a query through the form, it produces this error:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:    GET
>   Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/search?keywords=&city=Corpus+Christi
>   Raised by: listings.views.listing

It should render a ".com/listings/search" page.

Previously I had it working beautifully, but after I successfully changed the url path of single listings page - "listings/listing" to a string from an integer, it caused this problem for my search page.
Could be a coincidence, but I believe it could be connected.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='listings'),
  path('<str:listing_title>', views.listing, name='listing'),
  path('search', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from .choices import price_choices, city_choices, bed_choices, bath_choices

from .models import Listing
from agents.models import Agent
from contacts.models import Contact



def index(request):
  listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(is_published=True)

  paginator = Paginator(listings, 6)
  page = request.GET.get('page')
  paged_listings = paginator.get_page(page)

  context = {
    'listings': paged_listings,
    'price_choices': price_choices,
    'city_choices': city_choices,
    'bed_choices': bed_choices,
    'bath_choices': bath_choices
  }
  return render(request, 'listings/listings.html', context)




def listing(request, listing_title):
  listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, title=listing_title)
  context = {
    'listing': listing,
  }
  return render(request, 'listings/listing.html', context)




def search(request):
  queryset_list = Listing.objects.order_by('list_date')

  if 'keywords' in request.GET:
    keywords = request.GET['keywords']
    if keywords:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(description__icontains=keywords)

  if 'city' in request.GET:
    city = request.GET['city']
    if city:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(city__icontains=city)

  if 'pricerange' in request.GET:
    pricerange = request.GET['pricerange']
    if pricerange:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(price__lte=pricerange)

  if 'bed' in request.GET:
    bed = request.GET['bed']
    if bed:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(bedrooms__lte=bed)

  if 'bath' in request.GET:
    bath = request.GET['bath']
    if bath:
      queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(bathrooms__lte=bath)

  context = {
    'price_choices': price_choices,
    'city_choices': city_choices,
    'bed_choices': bed_choices,
    'bath_choices': bath_choices,
    'listings': queryset_list,
    'values': request.GET
  }

  return render(request, 'listings/search.html', context)
```

Comment: where is form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Django tries URL routes from top to bottom. So what is happening?**

When the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/search is summoned, Django is first trying

`path('<str:listing_title>', views.listing, name='listing'),`

and interpreting 'search' as the value of 'listing_title'. Because there is no listing named "search", the page returns a 404 error.

Change your `urls.py` to

```
  path('', views.index, name='listings'),
  path('search', views.search, name='search'),
  path('<str:listing_title>', views.listing, name='listing'),
```

And your code will work fine.